# Try to use Matlab CNN Resnet50 pre-trained model to convert ONNX to use in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, onnx

I first use `onnx2pytorch` to convert onnx to pytorch, and then use it to use the test set to get the accuracy.

```
model = torch.load("")
model.eval()
for epoch in range(1) :
    testing_loss = 0.0
    testing_correct = 0.0
    zpred, ztrue = [], []
    for test_inputs, test_labels in test_data :
        test_inputs, test_labels = test_inputs.to(device), test_labels.to(device)
        output = model(test_inputs) #error poit
        loss = criterion(output, test_labels)
        _, pred = torch.max(output.data, 1)
        testing_loss += loss.item() 
        testing_correct += torch.sum(pred == test_labels.data)
        output = (torch.max(torch.exp(output), 1)[1]).data.cpu().numpy()
        zpred.extend(output)
        testlabel = test_labels.data.cpu().numpy()
        ztrue.extend(testlabel)
    test_loss = testing_loss / len(test_loader)
    test_acc = 100 * testing_correct.cpu().numpy() / len(test_loader)

    print('Epoch is : {}, Test Loss is : {:.4f} Test Accuracy is :{:.4f}%'.format(epoch + 1, test_loss, test_acc))
```

I got this error, how can I fix the error like this?

```
sum() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (Tensor, Tensor), but expected one of:
 * (Tensor input, *, torch.dtype dtype)
 * (Tensor input, tuple of ints dim, bool keepdim, *, torch.dtype dtype, Tensor out)
 * (Tensor input, tuple of names dim, bool keepdim, *, torch.dtype dtype, Tensor out)
```

Is onnx model inference feasible on pytorch?
Thank you guys

Comment: Looks like `sum` got unexpected inputs. What does `pred == test_labels.data` give you? Can you verify that it is a tensor that `torch.sum` can take?

Comment: I print `test_labels.data` = tensor([2], device='cuda:0'), and it's type is `<class 'torch.Tensor'>` . I can't get `pred == test_labels.data` because the `output = model(test_inputs)` that row got error.

Comment: It is possible that the second argument to the sum() function was a Tensor instead of the expected "int or tuple of ints". `onnx2pytorch` authors may be able to help you with this.